# can I use Tensorflow.js for unsupervised learning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on my final year project which requires unsupervised learning. I have been looking forward to use tensorflow.js for this. But I am not sure that it provides unsupervised learning or not.

So, my question is this: can I use Tensorflow.js for unsupervised learning?

Answer (score -2):

There's not much difference in basic functionalities of TF.JS from TF, other than some minor differences in terms of speed, Gpu Support (Which can be used from browser itself as Major Browsers these days have Gpu acceleration enabled), using JS instead of Python to implement your models(Which you can just do it in JS too), other than that you should be good to go.

Here are some sources explaining some of differences with TF & TF Lite too, Hope that helps :

[**Machine Learning : Tensorflow v/s Tensorflow.js v/s Brain.js**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797280/machine-learning-tensorflow-v-s-tensorflow-js-v-s-brain-js)

[**Tensorflow js VS Tensorflow Lite**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860397/tensorflow-js-vs-tensorflow-lite)

[**Whats the difference between Tensorflow and Tensorflow.js?**](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/9xkjdq/whats_the_difference_between_tensorflow_and/)

[**What is the difference between the TensorFlow JS and TensorFlow Python apart from programming language? Is there anything that the TensorFlow Python can do that the TensorFlow JS cannot or vice versa?**](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-TensorFlow-JS-and-TensorFlow-Python-apart-from-programming-language-Is-there-anything-that-the-TensorFlow-Python-can-do-that-the-TensorFlow-JS-cannot-or-vice-versa)

[**Difference between Tensorflow and Tensorflow.js?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310539/difference-between-tensorflow-and-tensorflow-js)

Here also are some sources to get you started with the Lib :

[**TF-JS-Models**](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/models)

[**TF-Models-Github-Repo**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models)

[**TF Get started Guide**](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials)

[**Specialization: Basics of TensorFlow for JavaScript development**](https://www.tensorflow.org/resources/learn-ml/basics-of-tensorflow-for-js-development)